# How to create a "Settings" menu in a Firefox Addon?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, jpm

I'm using jpm/Addon Sdk to create a Firefox addon. My basic addon is ready but I want to have a "Settings" menu where users can select their preferences.

Can anyone guide me on how to go about it?

Thanks.

Comment: When using the add-on SDK, "Settings" (called "Preferences"), are usually done using [simple-prefs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs). You could have gotten this information from a simple Google search for "[Firefox addon SDK settings](https://www.google.com/search?q=Firefox+addon+SDK+settings)", or "[How to create a “Settings” menu in a Firefox Addon SDK](https://www.google.com/search?q=How+to+create+a+%E2%80%9CSettings%E2%80%9D+menu+in+a+Firefox+Addon+SDK)"

Comment: This question, as stated, is too broad. This site is for specific questions, not for guides on how to do something.  Please see [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Also, please try at least a [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=options+in+firefox+addon+sdk&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) next time. The first result shows you the `simple-prefs` module...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set this [**preferences**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json#preferences) in the package.json:

```json
{
  ...
  "preferences": [
     {
        "title": "What's your favorite color?",
        "name":  "someColorPreference",
        "type":  "color",
        "value": "#333"
     }
  ]
}
```

This will add a component that user can select some color. There are other [types of preferences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs#Preference_Types) too.

<kbd>[image: Example]</kbd>

Then, you can use [**`simple-prefs`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/simple-prefs) module to read, write and listen for preference changes:

```
let color = require('sdk/simple-prefs').prefs['someColorPreference'];
console.log(color); // #333
```

Comment: @AkshatKarnwal If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted (press the green tick underneath the voting buttons)

Comment: @AkshatKarnwal Click to accept this answer if it helps you :)